# iOS-swift How to make the table view with pagination?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination, swift2

I'm writing `JSON` data with lots of data. Sometimes several thousand records.

I want to use pagination to display, for example, 20 records per page.
When the user scrolls down, I want to add next 20 records.

Im sending current page( www.exampleRequest/&pageCounter=1 ) and receive 
adequate records

pageCouter = 1  => 1*20 =  0 to 20 records 

pageCouter = 2  => 2*20 = 21 to 40 records

But my question is how does the *iOS-swift* `UITableView` know when to get the next page of results?

Answer (score 2):

```
var pageIndex = 1
var dataSource = [DataSourceModel]()

func getDataSource() {

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "page": pageIndex
    ]
    Alamofire.request("Your URL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(data)
                self.procssGetResponce(json: json)
                print("response: \(json)")
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            break

        }
    }
}
func procssGetResponce(json: JSON) {
//Append Elements in your object 
    //dataSource.append(ELEMENTS)
    tblDataSource.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count + 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == dataSource.count {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoadCell") as! LoadMoreCell
        cell.loadProcess.startAnimating()
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tblDataSource.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId") as! PageListCell

        cell.dataSource = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.setDataSource()
        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == dataSource.count {
            pageIndex = pageIndex + 1
            getDataSource()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current count of data and include pull count in your query.

```
   var initialItems: Int = 0 //Intial Load Item
   var currentItems: Int! //Current Items
```

Use `NSMutableArray` to add your data and check for object available in previous data or not.

```
   //If previous load data don't contain the same data, update the array of loaddata.
   for object in json {
      if !loadeddata.containsObject(object){
          loadeddata.insertObject(object, atIndex: 0)
      }
   }
```